# Cannot use !heap -flt s in WinDbg Preview

Tags: windbg

I am trying to debug a memory leak with WinDbg Preview (the Windows Store application).

I can execute `!heap -s` to obtain the list of heaps, then `!heap -stat -h <address_of_a_heap>` to get statistics of the used memory by object, but when I try to list all instances of specified size using `!heap -flt s 100`, I get

```
HEAPEXT: !heap invalid option flag '-l'
Platform dependent usage:             
THIS EXTENSION SUPPORTS THE SEGMENT HEAP AND THE NT HEAP
```

The same commands work as expected in the classic WinDbg. I also get different output from the `!heap -stat -h` command for one and the same heap - e.g. in the classic WinDbg the output is a table with objects grouped by size.

Is there additional configuration that should be done to enable these commands?

Comment: Did you solved it? I got the same problem.

Comment: @Reven No, despite that using the "classic" WinDbg. Note that it gotten worse since I posted the question. As of now, if you install the latest classic WinDbg (using the latest Windows SDK), the commands doesn't work as well - I am thinking that they made the new debugging engine the default one. I had to install an [older Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) (e.g. 10.0.22000.194) to make the commands work.

What pisses me off is there's no documentation for the new commands.